# Macbook Pro wont open apps or download content due to Error Code: -50.

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software, error

My Macbook Pro ran into a problem and reported Error: -50.  I cannot open applications such as Chrome, Word, and others.  I cannot download content or move content to the trash because it says the disk is full, even though it still shows 80Gb of free storage.  The Ram is free and I cannot run ClamXav to see if it is a virus.  Disk Utility verifies the disk but the permissions have all changed and cannot be repaired.  Some permissions errors include "user differs on private/var/at, should be 0 user is 1"as well as various others.  I cant even see/open external drives I connect.  Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: [Recurring “error code -50/invalid argument” resolved by reboot, better solution sought](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/43533/8546) (2012-03-13)

Comment: [Finder error -50 when moving files from external NTFS hard disk](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/60358/8546) (2012-08-11) has an accepted answer. Whilst that question is about NTFS, it's useful to consider the origins of -50 and the range of situations in which the error may present.

Answer (score 1):

-50 is a file system error: "Error in user parameter list" (see https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1618)

What OS X version are you on? https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718 or [Will reinstalling Lion erase all my documents and applications?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26704/will-reinstalling-lion-erase-all-my-documents-and-applications) maybe helpful.

Comment: +1 for drawing attention to HT1618 (outdated and archived but still, a useful point of reference for many things). Whilst the error relates to the file system, it does does not necessarily indicate a problem at the file system level.